# Socket c# send data to SQLite Database, Database is closed

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have two apps with multiple Databases, a simple explanation is:

1. Main App: get the info from a database(firebase or SQLServer) and send by client socket to the second app.
2. Display App: get the socket info and insert into SQLite database, after shows the data in a WinForm.

My problem is sometimes Sqlite has an error doing the insert (Database is locked), because i need many inserts in a little time. I'm working in a payout machine and if the machine get 0,5€ have to send to the display quickly.

I use [MDSN Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example), and this modified code:

```
if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        {
            //This is amount to pay
            string searchString = "<EOF>";
            int endIndex = content.IndexOf(searchString);
            s = content.Substring(0, endIndex);
            string insertar = "INSERT INTO transacciones " +
                "VALUES  ('" + DateTime.Today + "','" + s + "',NULL);";
            //Insert
            SQLite bd = new SQLite();
            bd.Insert(insertar);
            Send(handler, content);
        }
else if (content.IndexOf("<REC>") > -1)
        {
            //This is the pay 
            SQLite bd = new SQLite();
            string searchString = "<REC>";
            int endIndex = content.IndexOf(searchString);
            s = content.Substring(0, endIndex);
            int id = bd.GetId();
            string insertar = "UPDATE transacciones " +
                "SET cobrado= '" + s + "' WHERE ROWID=" + id + ";";
            //Update
            bd.Insert(insertar); //here i have the problem   
            Send(handler, content);
        }
```

when I insert in the pay machine a lot of coins my display app begins to go slow and near the sixth update (sometimes more or less) i get the error:

**SQLite error (5): database is locked**

The function insert is:

```
public Boolean Insert(string sql)
        {
            try
            {
                SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("data source=" + Datos.dataBase + "\\bdDisplay.sqlite;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
                con.Open();
                
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
                
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                
                command.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Insert: " + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }            
        }
```

Maybe the error comes from do not parametricer?
Or comes from too many operations? in this case, can i do something to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is better to use `using(){}` or else you need to use

```
try{

} catch(){

}
finally{
  //to dispose
}
```

and it will improve performance if you use UnitOfWork style, like on your update part may be better to `Unite` it such:

```
        //This is the pay 
    SQLite bd = new SQLite();
    string searchString = "<REC>";
    int endIndex = content.IndexOf(searchString);
    s = content.Substring(0, endIndex);
    bd.Update(s);

    ....

    public bool Update(object value)
    {
       using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(...))
       {
            conn.Open();
            // GetId(). 
            //reconstruct sql command then 
            //do insert
       }
       // this way only use single conn for both getId and Insert
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't dispose when the error is received.

```
 using (SQLiteConnection c =
            new SQLiteConnection("data source=" + Datos.dataBase +
                                 "\\bdDisplay.sqlite;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"))
        {
            c.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, c))
            {
                var effect = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return effect > 0;
            }

        }
```

for you is big problem. maybe you need only finaly area.[how to use finaly area](https://stackify.com/csharp-exception-handling-best-practices/)